# Dynamic Radar Chart keeping track of points

Tags: javascript, graph, data-visualization

I'm building a dynamic radar chart, I got the code reviewed and followed the recommendation from fellow SO member.

This is how far I've come, but seem to have hit a roadblock:

```js
var canv = document.getElementById('canvas');
var canv1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var point_xy = document.getElementById('point_xy');
var tipCanvas = document.getElementById("tip");
var tipCtx = tipCanvas.getContext("2d");
var point_xy_cords = [
  []
];
var pentagon_one = 24;
var pentagon_two = 18;
var pentagon_three = 12;
var pentagon_four = 6;
var pentagon_five = 0;
var circles = [];
var contx = canv.getContext('2d');
var contx1 = canv1.getContext('2d');
var offsetX = canv1.offsetLeft;
var offsetY = canv1.offsetTop;
contx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);

function drawShape(ctx, x, y, points, radius1, radius2, alpha0) {
  //points: number of points (or number of sides for polygons)
  //radius1: "outer" radius of the star
  //radius2: "inner" radius of the star (if equal to radius1, a polygon is drawn)
  //angle0: initial angle (clockwise), by default, stars and polygons are 'pointing' up
  var radius_size = radius1;
  var i, angle, radius;
  if (radius2 !== radius1) {
    points = 2 * points;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    var temp = [];
    contx1.beginPath();
    for (var j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
      angle = j * 2 * Math.PI / points - Math.PI / 2 + alpha0;
      radius = j % 2 === 0 ? radius_size : radius_size;
      temp[j] = [(x + radius_size * Math.cos(angle)), (y + radius_size * Math.sin(angle))];
      ctx.lineTo(temp[j][0], temp[j][1]);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    style(ctx);
    radius_size = radius_size - 20;
    point_xy_cords.push(temp);
  }
  point_xy.textContent = "[1] = " + point_xy_cords[1] + " y = " + point_xy_cords[1][1];
}

function style(ctx, fill) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 109, 0, 1)";
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  if (fill) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(74, 157, 33, 0.6)";
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke()
  }

  //contx.fill();
}

var radius = 2;

var Circle = function(x, y, radius) {
  this.left = x - radius;
  this.top = y - radius;
  this.right = x + radius;
  this.bottom = y + radius;
  this.point_clicked = [];
  
  this.clicked = function(){
    points[1][0] = x; //hardcoded part
    points[1][1] = y; //hardcoded part
    contx1.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
    drawBackgroundPentagons(contx1);
    drawMainPentagon(contx1, points);
    drawPoints();
  }

  this.draw = function(ctx) {
    //Draw all points
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(74, 157, 33, 1)";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  
  this.containsPoint = function(x,y){
   return (x < this.right && x > this.left && y > this.top && y < this.bottom);
  }
};

//Draw background
function drawBackgroundPentagons(ctx) {
  drawShape(ctx, 120, 120, 5, 100, 100, 0);
}
drawBackgroundPentagons(contx1);

//Draw all the points
function drawPoints(){
  for (var x = 1; x <= 5; x++){
    for (var y = 0; y <= 4; y++){
      var circle = new Circle(point_xy_cords[x][y][0], point_xy_cords[x][y][1], 8);
      circle.draw(contx1);
      circles.push(circle);
    }
  }
}
drawPoints();
function drawMainPentagon(ctx, points) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(points[0][0], points[0][1]);
  for (var x = 1; x <= 4; x++) {
    ctx.lineTo(points[x][0], points[x][1]);
  }
    style(ctx, "fill");
   ctx.closePath();
}

points = point_xy_cords[1];
drawMainPentagon(contx1, points);

function handleMouseDown(e, message) {

  point_xy.textContent = (message);
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

canv1.onmousedown = function(e) {
  var pos = getMousePos(canv1, e);
  var clickedX = pos.x;
  var clickedY = pos.y;


  var tooltipText = "nothing";
  
  for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    var circle = circles[i];
    if (circle.containsPoint(clickedX, clickedY)) {
      circle.clicked();
      return;
    }
 }
  tooltip("points[0]", clickedX, clickedY);
};

function tooltip(text, clickedX, clickedY) {
  tipCtx.fillStyle = "black";
  tipCtx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  tipCtx.fillStyle = "white";
  tipCtx.fillText(text, 5, 10);
  tipCanvas.style.left = (clickedX + 15) + "px";
  tipCanvas.style.top = (clickedY - 26) + "px";
}

canv1.onmouseover = function(e) {
  return null;

}
canv1.onmouseout = function(e) {
  return null;
}
canv1.onmousemove = function(e) {
  return null;
}
```

```css
#tip {
  left: -200px;
  top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  maxWidth: 200px;
  backgroundColor: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border: rgba(45, 65, 45, 1);
  borderRadius: 5px;
  color: #f9f9f9;
  fontSize: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
  textAlign: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvasesdiv" style="position:relative; width:400px; height:300px">
  <canvas id="tip" width=100 height=100 style="z-index: 3;"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas" style="z-index: 1;
position:absolute;
left:10px;
top:10px;
" height="300px" width="400">
    This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
  </canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas1" style="z-index: 2;
position:absolute;
left:10px;
top:10px;
" height="300px" width="400">
    This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
  </canvas>

</div>
<div id='point_xy'></div>
```

If you click a point, it is suppose to move the point of the highlighted pentagon to the clicked point. It works, except I can't figure out what conditions to add in order to move the correct corner of the highlighted pentagon. In the above code I have hardcoded it, so that no matter which point you click, it will move point at index 0.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want to do is let each circle know what `spoke` or `radii` it belongs to. Something like this:

```
var Circle = function(x, y, radius, spoke, value) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.spoke = spoke;
  this.value = value;
```

Now create them something like:

```
function drawPoints() {
  for (var value = 1; value <= 5; value++){
    for (var spoke = 0; spoke <= 4; spoke++){
      var circle = new Circle(point_xy_cords[value][spoke][0], point_xy_cords[value][spoke][1], 8, spoke, value);
      circle.draw(contx1);
      circles.push(circle);
    }
  }
}
```

I changed the variable names to something meaningful. One note here is that you mix code to create the circles and code to draw them. You don't want to do this. Create them once on initialization and redraw them as changes are made (clicking). You don't want to re-create the circles every time you redraw.

Lastly change this:

```
// Circle
this.clicked = function(){
    points[this.spoke][0] = this.x;
    points[this.spoke][1] = this.y;
    updateCanvas();
}
```

And elsewhere:

```
function updateCanvas() { 
  contx1.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
  drawBackgroundPentagons(contx1);
  drawMainPentagon(contx1, points);
  drawPoints();
}
```

If I can make a suggestion, start with the simplest code you can. Start just by displaying the circles and pentagons, get that working cleanly and build onto it. Try and keep logic separate in your code. There are several places where you create objects and initialize arrays (like `coords`) while you are drawing which is both unnecssary but also means that you do it over and over instead of just once. There is a also lot of code here that is unnecessary.